# Usable screencast tool for Linux?

Tags: screencasting

..under windows.. I think Camtasia studio is the best screen recorder. But I just cant find any good tool for Linux (to be exact: Scientific Linux). What are the best tools for recording the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [recordmydestkop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/recordmydesktop/) to create screencasts in Linux.

Comment: Istanbul worked fine for me.